# User Preference GPO on a specific set of computers

Tags: group-policy, deployment

I hope you can help me with this situation:

I’ve been asked to deploy a specific wallpaper to front office computers. I’m not allowed to move the users from the Users OU container. This means the GPO will be created at the Users OU with a Security Filtering to a specific Security Group, right? 
Believing I know how to set the proper GPO to get the job done (deploying the wallpaper), what is the best method to specify the target computers? WMIC query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the policy at the computer's OU and use Group Policy Loopback Processing Mode.  If you want to preserve all of the other User policy settings, select Merge.  If there is a conflict (with the required setting(s)), select Replace.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2013/02/08/circle-back-to-loopback.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Loopback processing may be the best route to go, but you do have an additional option available since you specifically mention doing this using *preferences*.

Item level targeting in recent versions of AD can apply user settings while only matching specific OUs the logged in computer. For details on setting this up, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770424.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Loopback is not designed for such scenario. If you are talking about preference, you can use item targeting that come with Preferences

Answer (score 0):

User Group Policy Loopback Processing Mode was the right answer to my problem. Now I’m able to apply the user configuration settings to everyone who logs on the target computers!
I’ve found some trouble changing wallpaper due to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977944 but I was able to solve it with the explained workaround.

Once again, thank you for your time.